# CSS / jQuery - Text on image when hovering

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, mako

I have a hover function that puts the text under the image when hovering over. But I want the text over (on) the image. So that we you hover over the image will fade out a bit and the text will show.

Like this:
[image: Hover] [image: Hover2]

Can anyone please help me?

Here is the jQuery:

```
<%def name="javascript()">

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.category-box').each(function () {
           var hovertext = $(this).find('.hovertext').html();
           var hoverbox = $('<div id="hoverbox">' + hovertext + '</div>').css({
               'position': 'absolute',
               'top': $(this).css('top'),
               'left': $(this).css('left'),
               'width': $(this).css('width'),
               'background-color': '#f0f0f0',
               'z-index': 1000,
               'border-radius': '5px',
               '-moz-border-radius': '5px',
               '-webkit-border-radius': '5px',
               'display': 'none',
               'cursor': 'pointer'
           });

           $(this).find('h4').after(hoverbox);

           $(this).hover(function () {
               hoverbox.fadeIn('fast');
           }, function () {
               hoverbox.fadeOut('fast');
           });

           $(this).not('#mitp').click(function () {
               location.href = '${request.route_url('
               new_case ', category='
               ')}' + $(this).find('h4').html();
           });
       });

       $('#mitp').click(function () {
           location.href = '${request.route_url('
           mitp ')}';
       });
   });
```

The Mako:

```
% if categories:

% for category in categories:
    <div class="category-box">
        <img src="/category_icon/${category['id']}" width="120" height="120" />
        <h4>${category['name']}</h4>
        <span class="hovertext">
        % if category['description'] != '.':
            ${h.literal(category['description'])}
        % endif
        </span>
    </div>
% endfor
% endif
```

And the CSS:

```
.category-box {
    float: left;
    margin: 15px 10px 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
    min-height: 120px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.category-box:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.hovertext {
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: `.category-box:hover { opacity: .3 }` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. You are using `<div id="hoverbox">` for inserting musltiple elements, but that     means you have duplicated IDs in your document, which is not valid html
2. `.category-box` should have `position: relative;` that you can position the child elements properly with `position: absolute`
3. With the points above you can simply add `'top': 0, 'left': 0,` to your `hoverbox`

In your code `$(this).css('top')` will simply return the value `auto` which has no effect here.

---

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/s3xL1m5q/1/)**

Comment: Thank you so much! That helps a lot!

Comment: Do you know how I can get the hover-over to cover the image (except borders) like the example I posted? Now It's just grey where the text is.

Comment: @Kanari you can add `'height': $(this).find('img').css('height'),` to your hoverbox-code. The rest is simple css. Like `opacity` and positioning of the text.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.hover {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -150px 0px 0px 90px;
    width:90px;
    z-index:1;
}
.hover-content:hover .hover {
    display: block;
}
.hover-content:hover img {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover-content" style="display:inline-block;">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3zYD.jpg">
<div class="hover">
Your text here man!
</div>
</div>
<div class="hover-content" style="display:inline-block;">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3zYD.jpg">
<div class="hover">
Your text here man!
</div>
</div>
```